# Sublime color highlighter breaks after raw string literal

Tags: c++, c++11, sublimetext2

I'm trying out some C++11 features in sublime 2. I notice the the highlighter is broken after a raw string literal (probably because the unmatching quotations):

```
    string ss = R"STR(a\
        b\ test()"
        )STR";
    cout << ss <<endl;
```

Is there a setting or plugin to make it smarter?

Comment: As I post the question, I see even the stackoverflow highlighter is broken at the code.

Comment: I don't think so, no. I think other languages have this issue as well.

Comment: nowadays [just few compilers](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) even support this feature... so it is too early to talk about highlighters :)
PS: and btw, [kate](http://kate-editor.org/) [supports](http://kde-files.org/CONTENT/content-pre1/90660-1.png) it :)

Comment: @zaufi Thanks!I'm using llvm + clang++ 3.2, giving very good  C++11 support. Nice to know kate supports it. Any solution for sublime though?

Comment: sorry, I use only kate and never sublime...

Comment: You need to ask for support from sublime, this is not on topic here.

Comment: it was easy to make vim support this https://github.com/oblitum/Cpp11-Syntax-Support